# Using JRuby as a tool for java programming

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Anyone have real-world success stories, or links to them (blog posts, mailing list threads, etc) where JRuby has been used as a tool for quick prototyping, API exploration, REPL-based debugging, and so forth, in a pure Java project?

Comment: I don't seem to have a "community wiki" checkbox - someone with enough reputation please go ahead and mark this CW

Comment: @Marin CW is gone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192 Simply edit the question often enough to trigger CW.

Comment: oh! that seems annoyingly hacky; i'll just leave it alone, then, and let it go cw if it gets enough answers.

Comment: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/SuccessStories

Comment: @instantsetsuna that's not what i meant - i'm wondering about pure-java places where no jruby code is shipped, but it was nonetheless found useful as an internal development tool

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, I just thought it might be useful to you in someway.

Comment: no problem, and thanks for the link, it was interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

I built a small wrapper around some solrj classes ([jruby_streaming_update_solr_server](https://github.com/billdueber/jruby_streaming_update_solr_server)) and do all my solr indexing via jruby. I find it easier to write processing routines in ruby than java, and it's so easy to rapidly spit something out, test it, and run it that I'll never go back.